# Tuning MVC3 application that uses jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, performance

I'm trying to tune up my MVC3 application that uses a lot of jquery libraries, including jqGrid.
   I'd be interested to hear your best practices and performance tips and tricks if any.  What you normally do for 'most' MVC3 based applications as a given.

Thank you

Comment: Define `tuning` - are you talking about code simplicity, or how fast your page can load all resources?

Comment: If you present some actual evidence of a performance metric and what you want to be improved this question will survive. For now I vote for close.

Comment: Sorry I should've elaborated. Yes, I am speaking about load times. The perceived user experience when using your web application. I am looking to see how to improve load times when you have several jquery files that are already minified + your own. Does it normally cause an application to slow down tremendously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

If **tune** means better loading you can do these 3 things. You could optimize the loading time up to 80% with theese techniques.

I suggest to use [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see how your changes perform.

1. you should compress and combine your javascript files.
2. you should use the `OutputCache` Attribute if possible
3. you should remove unused `ViewEngines`

#### Sample

1. [Combine/Compress/Minify JS and CSS files in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/combineMinify.aspx)
2. [MSDN: OutputCacheAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx)

   ```
   [OutputCache(Duration=60)]
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       return View();
   }
   ```
3. do this in `global.asax`

   ```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       // other stuff

       ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();

       // if you only use RazorViewEngine
       ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());

       // if you only use WebFormViewEngine
       ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine());
   }
   ```

#### More Information

- [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)
- [Improving ASP.NET MVC Application Performance](http://www.slideshare.net/ardalis/improving-aspnet-mvc-application-performance)
- [MSDN: OutputCacheAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx)
- [Combine/Compress/Minify JS and CSS files in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/combineMinify.aspx)

Comment: W.r.t. jquery files, do you suggest using CDN or local versions for an application that could be intranet or internet based?  What would be the effect of either one of these?

Comment: On intranet i suggest local versions because you dont need internet acces. On internet based apps you can use CDN because these networks are fast as hell (made for this) and the chance is very high that a client has these scripts already in his cache.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [Yahoo recommendations](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) is a great way to optimize and speedup a website. Some of the tips are very easy to implement and could bring considerable performance gains.

Google have also published some [great resources](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rules_intro.html) that I strongly invite you to read.

Answer (score 1):

Combining and minifying your scripts is a great start to cut down the response size and number of requests. Also, be sure not to include uneccessary plugins and code that won't be used on particular pages...

Article on the topic:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx

For performance tuning on the server-side check out the `Mini Profiler` tool created and used by SO:

http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

Comment: Hi,Thank you for this. I have minified all my js files.  I have also scaled down images if any that I use in the application.